# What is the fastest way to convert the following byte array -> collection of class objects

Tags: c#, pointers, deserialization, marshalling, bit-shift

I have a byte array which can contain millions of bytes and is represented by the following structure: The array breaks down into n segments of 16 bytes each. The first 8 bytes of each segment represent a value of type long (8 bytes), followed by 2 values each of type short (2* 4 bytes).

I look for the absolute fastest way to convert the byte array segments into a collection of class objects of the following type:

```
public class Foo
{
    public long Value1 { get; set; }
    public float Value2 { get; set; }
    public float Value3 { get; set; }

    public Foo(long value1, float value2, float value3)
    {
        Value1 = value1;
        Value2 = value2;
        Value3 = value3;
    }
}
```

What I have tried done so far was using the BitConverter.ToInt64(...),... but the conversion takes way too long given I have to deal with arrays of sizes in the millions of bytes and several hundred of such arrays.

```
var collection = new List<Foo>();
        var byteArraySize = byteArray.Count();
        for (var counter = 0; counter < byteArraySize; counter += PacketLength) //Packetlength here is 16
        {
            collection.Add(new Foo(
                               BitConverter.ToInt64(byteArray, counter),
                               BitConverter.ToSingle(byteArray, counter + 8),
                               BitConverter.ToSingle(byteArray, counter + 12)));
        }
```

Can someone please show me how to apply bit-shift logic to speed up this procedure. Unsafe code, using pointer logic, would also work.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The fastest way would be to not convert the data to objects at all. If you already have the data in memory, just pass an index into the array around. For easy access, don't load the data as byte array but as a custom struct array.

Answer (score 2):

The following codes needs 4.668 seconds to process 1 GiB of data on my machine, out of which 0.028 seconds are spent on converting the data and 4.641 seconds on creating `Foo` objects. Your original code needs 6.227 seconds.

```
unsafe Foo[] Load(byte[] buffer, int offset, int length)
{
    fixed (byte* ptr = buffer)
    {
        Data* data = (Data*)(ptr + offset);
        Foo[] result = new Foo[length / sizeof(Data)];
        for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
        {
            result[i] = new Foo(data);
            data++;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

with

```
struct Data
{
    public long Value1;
    public float Value2;
    public float Value3;
}
```

and

```
class Foo
{
    public long Value1 { get; set; }
    public float Value2 { get; set; }
    public float Value3 { get; set; }

    public unsafe Foo(Data* data)
    {
        Value1 = data->Value1;
        Value2 = data->Value2;
        Value3 = data->Value3;
    }
}
```

Comment: what does `data++;` doing? Did you mean `ptr++`?

Comment: I see your point regarding your earlier comment now. Will need to think about it because I may be able to omit the DTOs, holding the three value types.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: `data++;` advances the `data` by one element. I mean it.

Comment: Ah, My mistake I overlooked it. missed `data` is being used in loop for creating `Foo`

Comment: @dtb, could you please elaborate what you mean with "For easy access, don't load the data as byte array but as a custom struct array."? Given the loaded data is initially only available as byte array, what do you mean with that comment?

Comment: The byte array has to come from somewhere. I don't know your code, but it may be possible to directly get a `Data[]` instead of a `byte[]`.

Comment: @dtb, the byte array originates from loading from a binary file.

Comment: Have a look at the [MemoryMappedFile Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.aspx) and the [MemoryMappedViewAccessor.ReadArray<T> Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267761.aspx).